# Is this ok when implementing multiple table views in Swift5?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm implementing two table views on a single view controller in Swift 5.  I realise this can be done with a single extension to the view controller by identifying the table views by name.  However, I'd like to keep the code separate, and so I've done it as shown in this simple example here - this has involved looking at several examples on the web and so a general thank you to all who post these things!  The main one is the answer by Girish Ghoda here:
[Two tables on one view in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26215475/two-tables-on-one-view-in-swift)

It all seems to work, but I'm wondering if I'm breaking any important rules...

There are two table views on the view controller, with simple constraints and outlets tableView1 and tableView2.

This is the ViewController.swift file

```
import UIKit

var array1 = ["one", "two", "three"]
var array2 = ["left", "right", "centre", "outside"]

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var tableView1: UITableView!
  @IBOutlet weak var tableView2: UITableView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    initTableViews()
  }

  var dataSource1: DataSource1!
  var dataSource2: DataSource2!

  func initTableViews() {
    dataSource1 = DataSource1()
    tableView1.dataSource = dataSource1
    tableView1.delegate = dataSource1

    dataSource2 = DataSource2()
    tableView2.dataSource = dataSource2
    tableView2.delegate = dataSource2

  }

}
```

There are then two files:

TableViewClass1.swift

```
import UIKit

class DataSource1: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

  override init(){
    super.init()
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return array1.count
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0

    cell.textLabel?.text = array1[indexPath.row]

    return cell
  }

}
```

TableViewClass2.swift:

```
import UIKit

class DataSource2: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

  override init(){
    super.init()
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return array2.count
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0

    cell.textLabel?.text = array2[indexPath.row]

    return cell
  }
}
```

As I say, everything seems ok, so it may seem strange to ask about it, but while the approach seems to give simple code structure, I'm wondering if there is anything here that could lead to problems.

Many thanks,
Ian

Comment: using two dataSources class is a good approach and it is help you in future instead of leading any problem. It is easy to maintain and understand for you and others as well.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine, but if both classes are that redundant I would use **one** `DataSource` class with a convenience initializer and lazy instantiated `dataSource` properties

```
class DataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var array : [String]
    let cellIdentifier : String

    init(array: [String], cellIdentifier : String )
    {
        self.array = array
        self.cellIdentifier = cellIdentifier
        super.init()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return array.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0

        cell.textLabel?.text = array[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

}
```

---

```
lazy var dataSource1: DataSource = {
    return DataSource(array: array1, cellIdentifier: "cell1")
}()

lazy var dataSource2: DataSource = {
    return DataSource(array: array2, cellIdentifier: "cell2")
}()


func initTableViews() {
  tableView1.dataSource = dataSource1
  tableView1.delegate = dataSource1

  tableView2.dataSource = dataSource2
  tableView2.delegate = dataSource2
}
```

Comment: Thanks @vadian - that's very neat.  I've implemented it and it is cleaner code than my approach...